# org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException on tomcat7

Tags: apache, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, tomcat7

I've been fighting with my tomcat server for a while now and it still doesn't work.
I'm using **tomcat7**, on Debian **Wheezy**, with **PostgreSQL v9.1**.
I tried everything possible, and here is what I'm keeping on getting :

```
database.DataBaseException: Database error while trying to get a new connection. Error information: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'
database.Connection$.getConnection(Connection.scala:20)
database.Users$.createRegisteredUser(Users.scala:58)
controllers.page.CreateAccountController.before(CreateAccountController.scala:36)
controllers.page.AbstractPageController.processRequest(AbstractPageController.scala:52)
controllers.page.AbstractPageController.doPost(AbstractPageController.scala:79)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

I have access to the application pages when I'm running my application and my tomcat server, so far I configured tomcat well enough for this, but as soon as I'm having an action that involves a request to the database (creation of user, etc.), I get this error !

As for the general context of the web application, I've started helping on an already existing project, I installed tomcat7 and cloned the source on my laptop. It works well with the other people working on it - and I haven't made any change to the application code so far (the code works fine): so the error definitely comes from my tomcat configuration and not from the code.

To configure a Tomcat7 server for a web application, what we have to do to configure is creating a context.xml in the META-INF/ directory right ?
I've also added a  for the data source to the WEB-INF/web.xml file but it doesn't seem to be mandatory to have a tomcat7 application data source work fine.
I've copied and past my META-INF/context.xml file to Catalina/localhost/ directory with .xml.
I've added the postgres jdbc jar to /usr/share/tomcat7/lib (I've seen a lot of forum posts talking about a conf/lib but I can't find it so I figured it's this lib)

I've read things about tweaking with the tomcat context.xml file and whatnot, but there are pros and cons, and anyway it doesn't work either for me.

Here is my context.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Context>
  <Resource name="jdbc/dbname"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            username="user1"
            password="user1"
            driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
        url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname"
            maxActive="8"
            maxIdle="4"/>
   <Environment name="encryptionKey" type="java.lang.String" value="<the key>" override="false"/>
</Context>
```

What I added to the WEB-INF/web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/dbname</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
```

The code sample where it all starts (application written in scala) :

```
private val ds: DataSource = new javax.naming.InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/dbname").asInstanceOf[DataSource]
    private var connec: java.sql.Connection = null

    def getConnection(): java.sql.Connection = {
        try {
            if (connec == null) {
                connec = ds.getConnection() //here is raised the error
                connec.setAutoCommit(false)
            }
            connec
        } catch {
            case ex: SQLException => throw new DataBaseException("Database error while trying to get a new connection. Error information: " + ex.toString())
        }
    }
```

I tried to run the application without context.xml and without the copy of if in the Catalina/localhost directory, and I get the same error. I guess the server just doesn't find my context.xml file ?

The last thing is I've compared my context.xml with some other people from the project, and they have exactly the same - and it works for them (except the db name and password that depends on what they chose)....
I also made sure the port 5432 is the right one, and it is.

Yes, it's pretty puzzly !

If you want more precision (I might be missing relevant things) don't hesitate to ask me !

Comment: Please, edit your question and provide the stacktrace (catalina.out or IDE console).

Comment: This is way above the PostgreSQL level, it's not even invoking pgJDBC. It's a misconfiguration in your appserver context or orm environment. The vital part of the error message is `Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null`.

Comment: Yes it seems it is not configured well enough for the app to find how to get to the database... The thing is I've tried everything possible and every solution tried by people all over the internet, and I might be missing something since it's still not functionning :-/

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue. I am facing same.